# 遅刻している vs 遅刻する for saying "I am late."

Tags: grammar, usage, conjugations

I'm trying to figure out if I should use 遅刻する or 遅刻している for expressing "I am late to..."

For example, I was thinking, 仕事初日に遅刻しているだけじゃなく、迷子になってしまった。"Not only am I late to my first day on the job, but I've gotten lost, too." I thought this was correct, but since 遅刻 already means "to be late/tardy", is the resultant state ーしている redundant? Also, a similar question for 迷子になってしまった. Should I be using the past tense here or the resultant state? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its original sense, 遅刻する refers to a punctual act of arriving late. So, if you are talking about a late arrival that is likely to happen, you should use 遅刻する.

> 仕事初日に遅刻するだけじゃなく、〜
> Not only I’m going to be/arrive late on my first day on the job, …

However, 遅刻している is also fine as it is understood as referring to either one of the following two states.

> 仕事初日に遅刻しているだけじゃなく、〜
> a) Not only I’m (running) late for work on my first day on the job, …
> b) Not only I’m making the mistake of being/arriving late on my first day on the job, …

The first is about the fact of being late, whereas the second sounds like an answer to the self-accusatory question of *What am I doing?!* I know these two are different, but I’m find it hard to explain...

When said about yourself, 迷子になっている or 迷子になってしまっている would be understood similarly to (b) above. It’s good as a statement about an ongoing state of another person.

迷子になった or 迷子になってしまった refers to the event of getting lost that has already happened and thus put you in the current state.